# How to select multiple values after using Max() in LINQ to Objects?

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-objects

I have the following LINQ query:

```
var query =
    (from p in obj1
     group p by p.objID into g
     let totalSum = g.Sum(p => p.ObjPrice)
     select new { MyObjectID = g.Key, totalSum })
    .Max(g => g.totalSum);
```

I want to select both the object id and price of the object with the maximum price.  How can I do that?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use an order by descending clause and call `FirstOrDefault()`.

```
(from p in obj1
group p by p.objID into g
let totalSum = g.Sum(p => p.ObjPrice)
orderby totalSum descending
select new { MyObjectID = g.Key, totalSum }).FirstOrDefault();
```

Comment: is `{ MyObjectId = g.key, totalSum }` a legal construct? Should `totalSum` get assigned to a property? Just asking as I've never seen that before.

Comment: @Matt Greer It works in C#3 (just tried in LINQPad ;-) -- same as `..., totalSum = totalSum }` but pure voodoo if you ask me. Also works on compound identifiers (`g.Key`, e.g. -> takes last identifier -- `Key` here -- as key).

Comment: @Matt: Yes it's valid.  When you create an anonymous object, there's two ways to set the properties: declare it and set the value `MyObjectId = g.Key` or declare a variable to take the name _and_ value from.  So this is equivalent: `new { MyObjectID = k.Key, totalSum = totalSum }`

Comment: will this work if you have multiple objects/groups having maximum price ? i have not tried this